# Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object for ISearchIndexClient.Documents.Search method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure

I am using Azure search and this is my unit test code:

```
var expectedResponse = new DocumentSearchResult { };
var _searchIndexRepository = new Mock<ISearchIndexClient>();
_searchIndexRepository
            .Setup(r => r.Documents.Search(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<SearchParameters>(), It.IsAny<SearchRequestOptions>()))
            .Returns(expectedResponse);
```

The error at the time of setup, I get is:

> Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object

Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: [`Search`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.documentsoperationsextensions.search?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Search_DocumentsOperationsExtensions_Search_Microsoft_Azure_Search_IDocumentsOperations_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchParameters_Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchRequestOptions_) is an extension method, and Moq cannot mock extension methods. You would need to check what the extension method accesses and then mock that so that the extension method can exercise to completion.

Comment: Use Microsoft Fakes or Pose (https://github.com/tonerdo/pose) to shim extension methods

Comment: *Some advice:* do not mock what you do not own/control. encapsulate them behind abstractions you control so as to decouple your code from 3rd party dependencies. This will allow for greater flexibility when testing your code in isolation.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the suggestions.  Below work around solved my problem:

I created a wrapper for SearchIndexClient like this:

```
public interface ICustomSearchIndexClient
{
    DocumentSearchResult<T> Search<T>(string searchTerm, SearchParameters parameters) where T : class;
}

public class CustomSearchIndexClient : ICustomSearchIndexClient
{
    private readonly SearchIndexClient _searchIndexClient;

    public CustomSearchIndexClient(string searchServiceName, string indexName, string apiKey)
    {
        _searchIndexClient = new SearchIndexClient(searchServiceName, indexName, new SearchCredentials(apiKey));
    }

    public DocumentSearchResult<T> Search<T>(string searchTerm, SearchParameters parameters) where T: class
    {
        return _searchIndexClient.Documents.Search<T>(searchTerm, parameters);
    }
}
```

Changed business logic like this:

Constructor:

```
public CustomSearchService(string serviceName, string apiKey, string indexName, ICustomSearchIndexClient customSearchIndexClient)
{
    _serviceName = serviceName;
    _apiKey = apiKey;
    _indexName = indexName;
    _customSearchIndexClient = customSearchIndexClient;
}
```

Search method:

```
public DocumentSearchResult<CustomSearchResult> Search(string search)
{
    return _customSearchIndexClient.Search<CustomSearchResult>(string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? "*" : search, null)
}
```

Changed my unit test like this:

```
[TestCategory("UnitTest")]
[TestMethod]
public void SearchTest()
{
    //Arrange
    var expectedResponse = new DocumentSearchResult<Models.CustomSearchResult> {  Count = 1, Results = <instantiate your custom model here>, Facets = < instantiate your custom model here > };

    var searchIndexClient = new Mock<ICustomSearchIndexClient>();
    searchIndexClient.Setup(r => r.Search<Models.CustomSearchResult>(It.IsAny<string>(), null)).Returns(expectedResponse);
    var business = new CustomSearchService("serviceName", "apiKey", "indexname", searchIndexClient.Object);

    //Act
    var result = business.Search("search term");

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result, "Business logic method returned NULL");
}
```

The wrapper ICustomSearchIndex is injected into CustomSearchService business logic using ninject:

```
Bind<ICustomSearchIndexClient>().To<CustomSearchIndexClient>();
Bind<ICustomSearchService>().To<CustomSearchService>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("serviceName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchServiceName"])
    .WithConstructorArgument("apiKey", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchServiceApiKey"])
    .WithConstructorArgument("indexName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IndexName"]);
```